# connected to wireless but no Internet

Tags: wireless, internet

I'm connected to my wireless network but unable to connect to the Internet. I restart my laptop several time but nothing happened. if I attempt to browse the web (or do anything else that requires an Internet connection), I get a "connection not found" error.I don't think the problem is with the network or the hardware, because if I boot into windows, everything is fine. And also this is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:48:84:63  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:5092 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5092 (5.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:6d:57:c6:2f:04  
      inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::466d:57ff:fec6:2f04/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:2482 (2.4 KB)  TX bytes:10856 (10.8 KB)
```

,

```
$ ping -c3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

,

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the WIFI u connected to has no internet access. Check with your ISP.

Comment: there are several computer which using same wifi and they access to internet